# Copy files from Google Cloud Shell to GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

My development environment is within Google Cloud Shell, whereas the production environment is a separate GCP VM instance. After testing I would like to move all files from my dist folder to the GCP VM instance.

As a test I have tried to copy just one file.

**Attempt #1: within Cloud Shell terminal**

`gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:~/README-cloudshell.txt peter@myvm:~/README-cloudshell.txt`

Error #1: All sources must be local files when destination is remote.

**Attempt #2: within GCP VM terminal**

`gcloud compute scp cloudshell:~/README-cloudshell.txt myvm:~`

Error #2: All sources must be local files when destination is remote.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from cloud shell

`gcloud compute scp ~/README-cloudshell.txt user@instanceName:~`

Use a correct SSH key or set the correct permission in the `~` directory